# .htaccess rewrite rules not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am using scssphp for my css preprocessing and right now my styles look like `src="style.php/style.scss"`. What I was wanting is to use a htaccess to just write in the style and then anything ending in `.scss` would get run through `style.php`.  So I tried putting this in my home directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.scss$ style.php/$1.scss
```

I even tried

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.scss$ style.php/style.scss
```

Neither work, something is happening, because my style.scss is loading with a 500 internal server error, but I'm not sure where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are looping, try adding an additional check to not rewrite when the URI has style.php in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !style\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.scss$ style.php/$1.scss
```

The rewrite engine will continue to loop through your rules until the URI stops chanmging. What's happening with your rule is that a request like `/path/style.scss` is getting procfessed and rewritten to `/style.php/path/style.scss`, and the the rewrite engine loops. The second time around, the rule gets applied again and it rewrites to: `/style.php/style.php/path/style.scss`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

a better regex to get requested file name would be `[a-z_A-Z]+.scss`

try your htaccess using this syntax